# Существует ли поток, который может считывать и записывать данные одновременно?

Tags: java

Существует ли поток в java, который может считывать и записывать данные одновременно?

Comment: Конечно, а почему нет?

Comment: @VladD, Мне кажется речь об I/O Stream, а не о Thread